# Print large data in the frontend using ngTable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, printing, datatable, ngtable

I have seen a couple of questions related to printing large table data, but couldn't find a exact solution.

Here is the link to the data table : http://jsfiddle.net/bdeepakreddy/rho8jz0x/1/

I'm trying to print the data in the table with multiple pages, not able to get it done. Even tried with the alternate following code.

```
$scope.previewFields = function(){
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=600,width=700');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title><style type="text/css">body{font-family: "Roboto",Arial,sans-serif;overflow:visible;}.ng-table-filters,.ng-table-counts{display: none;} tr {border-top: 1px solid #f2f6f9;} .data-table{overflow: visible;} table{overflow:visible;}body, h1, h2, h3, ol, ul, div {     width: auto;     border: 0;     margin: 0 5%;     padding: 0;     float: none;     position: static;     overflow: visible; }</style>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById('printable').innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}
```

I'm OK with any solution, either with jQuery or Angular as long as it prints all the columns and rows.

Comment: Have you tried ui-grid form http://ui-grid.info/ instead? It is more geared towards larger datasets so might suite you better. I have not used it for printing though so can not comment in how good it is at that.